# How to integrate Google pay in react application

Tags: reactjs, google-pay

I need to integrate google pay in my react application but i am not getting proper article on this.is it possible to integrate google pay in react application?and how can i implement it?

Answer (score 1):

We've just [published and launched](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/simpler-google-pay-integration-for-react-web-developers.html) the [@google-pay/button-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-react).

You can install it with:

```
npm install @google-pay/button-react
```

Alternatively, you can try it out on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwndx7b/).

Please raise a GitHub issue if you have any problems with it.

For an example of how to Google Pay is integrated into a demo store, check out the following repository: https://github.com/google-pay/react-store/compare/google-pay

Note that you will also need to sign up for a Google Pay merchant account before you can launch: http://pay.google.com/business/console

EDIT:

Updated to include a JSFiddle link.

EDIT 2:

Updated with link to official launch post.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try with @google-pay/button-react this package.